# How to do extension based caching in IIS

Tags: caching, iis, iis-7.5

I am working on a project where I have to do extension based caching for a site hosted in IIS 7.5.

I am using this code part in the `web.config`:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:10:00" />
</staticContent>
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".aspx" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" /> 
        <add extension=".xml" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="10:00:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".php" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" /> 
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".png" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="10:00:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".axd" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="10:00:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".txt" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:05:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".html" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".htm" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".vbs" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:10:00" location="Downstream" />
        <add extension=".flv" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="10:00:00" location="Downstream" />
    </profiles>
</caching>
```

But somehow, on every extension, I am getting only 10 minutes of cache TTL.

Is there something else I have to do to get this work?